# How can I run a batch project with two independent jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

I am starting to create a project in `Spring Batch`, I have created two different classes that have no relation to each other.

This is the `NotificationOne.java` class:

```
@Slf4j
public class NotificationOne {
   public NotificationDataOne {
      log.info("NotificationDataOne");
   }
}
```

This is the `NotificationTwo.java` class:

```
@Slf4j
public class NotificationOTwo {
   public NotificationDataTwo {
      log.info("NotificationDataTwo");
   }
}
```

And this is the kind of configuration that I currently have but I don't know how to complete it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobBatchConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public Job jobOne(NotificationOne notificationOne) {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobOne").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
          .listener(notificationOne).flow(null).end().build();
    }  

}
```

What I need is to be able to start both classes and configure it in the config class.

Answer (score 0):

> the only thing is to execute that class but I do not know how to create or modify the configuration case. Please can you tell me how can I launch the Job?

Here is an quick hello world job and how to launch it from a `main` method:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("hello world");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        })
                        .build())
                .listener(new NotificationOne())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    static class NotificationOne implements JobExecutionListener {

        @Override
        public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            System.out.println("NotificationOne.beforeJob");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            System.out.println("NotificationOne.afterJob");
        }
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
NotificationOne.beforeJob
hello world
NotificationOne.afterJob
```

Comment: Ok yes, you are showing a message from the configuration file, but I want to be able to launch the NotificationOne class that I have created, not show a message from the configuration file. Because this class will have more logic in the future and I don't think it's good to add everything in that file

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of your `NotificationOne` that you are trying to pass as a listener to your job definition: `jobBuilderFactory.get("jobOne").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
.listener(notificationOne).flow(null).end().build()`. As said in my initial comment, to use that class as a listener you need to either implement `JobExecutionListener` or annotate methods with `@BeforeJob`/`@AfterJob`. In my answer, I used the first approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but the hello world that appears on the console is that of the NotificationOne class or the sysout of the tasklet of the configuration file? I don't know if my problem is understood?

Comment: The "hello world" is from the tasklet. "NotificationOne.beforeJob" and "NotificationOne.afterJob" are from the listener. You can adapt the sample as you want (remove the tasklet and change it with what you need to do).

Comment: Sorry but I can't adapt it to what I want to do. My problem is the following, I have a NotificationOne.java class, which I want to execute from MyJobConfiguration.java, without showing a message in this class, if not showing the message of the NotificationOne class. This is what I can not do, I do not know if it would work with the example you have set but I can not launch it.

Comment: Please, how can I execute the NotificationOne class from MyJobConfiguration, which is the message that is displayed is the Hello world of NotificationOne not the one of the sysout of MyJobConfiguration? I can't run it

Comment: Sorry, but `execute the NotificationOne class from MyJobConfiguration` does not make sense. You can't "execute" a class. You need to write a `main` method to run your code. In your case, `NotificationOne` as such can do nothing on its own, you need to register it as a listener in your job and run your job. Spring Batch will then call your code when appropriate (in this case, before/after the job). I hope you understand how frameworks work.

Comment: Yes, I understand how it works, what I want to achieve is to show the message of the NotificationOne class, without putting the message directly in the main. But i can't do it